# How do I maintain PHP sessions across multiple domains on the same server?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am looking for a way to maintain PHP sessions across multiple domains on the same server. I am going to be integrating my sites with a Simple Machines Forum so I will need to use MySQL based sessions. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending upon your preferred method of modifying PHP variables (Apache's config, .htaccess), change the session.cookie_domain value to be a consistent value.

I have multiple sub-domains, and each VirtualHost section in the Apache config file contains the following line:

php_value session.cookie_domain  mydomain.com

The syntax should be similar if you make the changes in a .htaccess file.

Updated for bobert5064's comment:

For multiple domains (ie domain1.com, domain2.org), I think it is only necessary to choose a common domain name (ie domain1.com).  I have never tried this, so I cannot verify that it works, but the logic seems accurate.

There is also a method to set the variables direction in PHP described at http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php.  The documentation makes no reference to the ability or inability to set cookies on a different domain.

Comment: The problem is that I am using multiple distinct URLs, not sub-domains. i.e. domain1.com domain2.com

Answer (score 1):

If one site is going to forward or link to a second it can include the session id in the *href* of the link or as an *input* in a form. Similar to George's *img tag* method, but the session would only move over if and when it was needed.

Which is best depends on the usage pattern of your sites really.