# How to access the session/Cookie set in the web service by another Site:

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a client application which will call the web method and pass two values (order and Amount).
The web method will set the values in Session/Cookie. Now the client application will redirect to other web site, the web site should be able to get the order and  Amount values either by Session/Cookie. I cannot use it as query string due to security issue. Kindly help me with a proper solution.
The code in web service is as follows:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true,Description="SetValues")]
    public void CallService(string orderNumber, double amount)
    {
        if (orderNumber != null && orderNumber != string.Empty)
        {               
          Context.Session["OrderID"] = orderNumber;
          Context.Session["Amount"] = amount; //Tried Session but did no work            
         //Tried Setting the value in Cookie 
          HttpCookie OrderID = new HttpCookie("OrderID",orderNumber);
          HttpCookie Amount = new HttpCookie("Amount", amount.ToString());
          OrderID.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
          Amount.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
          Context.Response.SetCookie(Amount);
          Context.Response.SetCookie(OrderID);
        }
}
```

//The code to get the values from Cookie

```
        Service.ServiceAPISoapClient e1 = new Service.ServiceAPISoapClient();           
           e1.CallEISService("12e", 121);
 string amount= Request.Cookies["Amount"] != null?  Request.Cookies["Amount"].Value:"";
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315132/how-do-i-use-cookies-across-two-different-domains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually to send info from one site to another all people use a form...

Put two hidden controls into a form. Then when submit the form you can read the values from these controls...

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are always bound to a single domain.
You cannot use your cookies in any other domain for security reasons.

Comment: @luc-Is there any other way to pass values from one application to another.

Comment: @psobhan can you set HttpHeaders for the request?

Comment: Maybe it is an idea to store the data in a database with a hash code as ID. Send the Hashcode with a POST or GET request to the other site , retrieve the data, Store it in a Session and delete the row in the database. I guess it is a security leak but I don't know any other way.