# Login from different Website, passing parameter trough URL

Tags: php, security, url, authentication

I have question about log-in from different Website.

> Is it possible that a user can login from **Website A** to **Website
>   B** by passing parameter (username and password) trough URL?

For example, I have login Form (contain username and password field) in **Website A**, than when user click submit, parameter will pass trough URL, and redirect to **Website B** (already login)

I have seen an article that allow it, something like

```
http://mydomain.com/login.php?username=iqbal&password=12345
```

but i don't know how to use it. Is it safe to use?

Comment: is website a or b a sub-domain of the other? if not then you could create a API on the other website to set the cookie/permissions. if you use the post using your get variables with sensitive information your playing with fire.

Comment: I wouldn't send a username and password trough url. Use [cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315132/how-do-i-use-cookies-across-two-different-domains) for that

Comment: website A is a folder : http://mydomain.com/website, and 
website B is subdomain : http://crm.mydomain.com

Comment: In short, yes. However, does Website B support this? What have you tried? Your question needs to provide more details and be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per: [Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)

Here are 3 options.

Place this in your php.ini:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
```

In your .htaccess:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com
```

As the first thing in your script:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I will look up for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Passing a password through a URL in plain text is NOT safe to use. Another method such as generating a random, one-use key should be used if anything

Comment: You should probably write some kind of communication API so that your two websites can communicate with one another regarding logins. Website A would talk to Website B and ask for a unique login key to be generated for User X. Website B would update it's user table to reflect the generated login key and it would be returned to Website A (This is all done in the background). Website A would then have the ability to generate a "login url" using this key and the user ID, so that when it's clicked Website B would be able to check the ID and key against its user table and log the user into the site

Comment: I'd recommend a bit more security too, you could add an expiry time to the login key so that it's only valid for X seconds or minutes and you possibly add stuff in to check if the referral URL is what is expected etc. There's loads of things you could add for extra security

Comment: okay i will. I still looking for answer based on your suggestion. :)