# How can I login to multiple applications in different domains once?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, multiple-domains

For example I have 2 apps, one is in `abc.com`, and another one is in `xyz.com`.

Now what I want to do is, if one user logged in `abc.com`, then he will be also logged in `xyz.com` automatically. Means after he logged in `abc.com`, and just open `xyz.com` in a new tab of browser, he will be showed that he has already logged in.

It's same as `msn.com` and `hotmail.com`, if you logged in `msn.com`, and open `hotmail.com`, you can see you've already logged in.

I'm using **CI**, and for login information I used CI's session functions (which is **cookie** in fact), but seems cookies cannot be shared cross different domains.

I've tried to use CURL, but CURL cannot make `xyz.com` *really* make the cookies.

And I've also searched around Google, many people suggested to pass a session id, but the problem is, there's no link between `abc.com` and `xyz.com`, **how can I pass the session**? If I store the session id in database, then how can I identify which user should use this session id? By IP is not secure obviously :D

Please, help me!

Comment: So what you're looking for is basically a Single Sign-on (or SSO in short) solution? Read up on OpenID (as used here on SO), it's tried and tested (and very convenient).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open an iframe on xyz.com that will connect to abc.com, then use ajax/js to forward some sort of token to xyz.com from the iframe by calling a js function from the iframe.

So it will look something like:

XYZ.com:

```
function authAbcUser(token) { 
    //During this function you will set a cookie for this user on XYZ.com
}
<iframe height="0" width="0" src="http://www.abc.com/auth.php?token"></iframe>
```

ABC.com/auth.php:

```
parent.authAbcUser(token);
```

Comment: hmmmmm, sry but how abt the security thing ?

Comment: i think i've already got the way to make it secure, many thx again !

Comment: Check where the request originated from perhaps? It wouldn't be completely safe, but probably would for smaller applications. See the solutions and explanations given in this question which is basically a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342378/cross-domain-login-how-to-login-a-user-automatically-when-transfered-from-one-d

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this and make it work with CI

http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/attachpass/Single_Sign_On_Process