# How can I keep my users logged in when visiting a sub-domain with PHP sessions?

Tags: php, session

Is it possible to keep a PHP Session active when the user accesses the sub-domain of a site? Example: If a user visits www.example.com they're not logged in, but they're logged in on example.com

And, I want to make user profiles on username.example.com, but if I do that, they're not logged in for sub-domains.

I'm using the `session_start();` function in php to handle the logins.

Comment: is that domain and sub domain running on same server (Apache)?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091677/php-authentication-with-multiple-domains-and-subdomains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use cookies instead of sessions. They are very similar but will remain intact over subdomains.