# session between domain and subdomains. What if the server hosts multiple domains

Tags: php, apache, cookies

I have a domain `myexampledomain.com` with some subdomains in it.

So I set

```
session.cookie_domain = .myexampledomain.com
```

and everything works fine for the domain and all the subdomain.

But this is set in `php.ini` so it is at server level. Now I want to configure a new domain on the same server. Say `myotherdomain.com`. I want this other domain to handle its own cookies without mixing with `myexampledomain.com`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091677/php-authentication-with-multiple-domains-and-subdomains) is about sharing the cookie between the two domains, I want it to be the opposite. How can I do it? The two domains have indipendent login systems and once the user is logged in a cookie is set. I want to set both cookies but each of them should be valid only for that domain. How should I change the php.ini for that? I think that `session.cookie_domain = .myexampledomain.com` will prevent to set cookies for `myotherdomain.com`

EDIT: I know how to handle this on the lower level (code level - php files) but I want to understand if there is a way to handle this at php.ini level (if this is feasible)

Comment: Do not force it in the file (leave it blank), force it in the code, using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php.  Each domain's files include a small PHP file to set that up for it's own context.  It says *Set cookie parameters defined in the php.ini file. The effect of this function only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and before session_start() is called.*

Comment: Or set the domain explicitly in the call to setcookie()

Comment: @Nic3500 thanks, I know this alternative. The question is different: is there a way to do it using php.ini? It is a specific question and the answer may also be "no".

Comment: Hi, turns out you can (I did not think so).  Look at https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php

Comment: @Nic3500 thanks. This is very usefull, will try it.

Comment: @Nic3500 no, actually you can't. Each Apache2 instance can use only one php.ini so only first PHPINIDir directive honored per configuration tree - subsequent ones ignored. It is possible using php_value directive inside vhost configuration specifying each value to be changed (luckily for me it is just one)

Comment: ok thanks for letting me know.  so you would be stuck with many instances of the whole suite (apache + php)... I will keep an eye out if you ever post some solution.

Comment: if you read my last comment there is already a solution posted. Not for the whole php.ini but to ovrerride single parameters